# React final form at least one mandatory field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

I have the following:

```
export const isOneFieldValid = (val: string) => { 
  console.log(val)
  return val ? undefined : true
}

...
const validate = (field: string) => {
  switch (field) {
    case 'email': {
      return composeValidators(isOneFieldValid, isValidEmail, hasStringeMaxLength)
    }
    case 'workPhone':
    case 'homePhone':
    case 'mobile': {
      return composeValidators(isOneFieldValid, isNumber, hasNumberMaxLength)
    }
    default:
      return undefined
  }
}
...
```

This validates all of the 4 fields, but is there a way to validate only one field assuming that all of them are empty?

As long as there is one way to contact the user I can submit the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you need a form level validation, not field level?

```
<Form
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
    validate={values => {
            const errors = {}
            if (values.email && isValidEmail && hasStringMaxLength) {
              return ;
            } else {
             errors.email = 'Require';
            }
            if (writeFunctionToCheckWorkPhone) {
              return;
            } else {
              error.workPhone = 'Require';
            }
            if (writeFunctionToCheckHomePhone) {
              return ;
            } else {
              error.homePhone = 'Require';
            }
           if (writeFunctionToCheckMobile) {
              return ;
            } else {
              error.mobile = 'Require';
            }
            return errors;
          }}
    ...
```